# WebApi - Passing an Array of Values

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to build an API using ASP.NET Web API (version 4.5.2). To get started, I'm just trying to create a basic endpoint that adds some numbers. In an attempt to do this, I've created:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IEnumerable<int> Calulate(decimal[] op1, decimal[] op2)
  {
    var results = new List<Calculation>();
    for (var i=0; i<op1.Length; i++) 
    {
      var calculation = new Calculation();
      calculation.Operand1 = op1[i];
      calculation.Operand2 = op2[i];
      calculation.Calculate();

      results.Add(calculation);
    }
    return results;
  }

  public class Calculation
  {
    public int Operand1 { get; set; }
    public int Operand2 { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }

    public void Calculate()
    {
      this.Result = this.Operand1 + this.Operand2;
    }
  }
}
```

I am now trying to hit this endpoint via the Postman Chrome app. When I run it via Postman, I'm getting an error. Here is what I'm doing:

In Postman, I've put "http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate" in the URL field next to the "GET" drop down. I then click "Send". I'm receiving the following error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('op1' and 'op2') to the request's content.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "..."
}
```

I think (I don't know) the cause is because I'm not passing the values to the API from Postman correctly. However, I'm not sure how to do that. How do I pass an array of values to an API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Short answer

To send arrays of decimals, WebApi expects url signature like:
GET http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate?Operand1=1.0&Operand1=2.0&Operand2=3.0&Operand2=4.0

That url will send [1.0,2.0] as Operand1 and [3.0,4.0] as Operand2.

## Long answer

By calling your api using GET http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate, you actually send nothing to your server. (aside of headers content)

If you want to send data to your server, you have (at least) 2 options:

Option 2: Use GET method if operation is idempotent
Like William Xifaras already pointed out, specify that your inputs will come from the URL so WebApi interprets properly. To do so, use [FromUri].

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("calculate")]
    public List<Calculation> CalculateWithGet([FromUri]decimal[] Operand1, [FromUri]decimal[] Operand2)
    {
        var results = new List<Calculation>();
        for (var i = 0; i < Operand1.Length; i++)
        {
            var calculation = new Calculation();
            calculation.Operand1 = Operand1[i];
            calculation.Operand2 = Operand2[i];
            calculation.Calculate();

            results.Add(calculation);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public class Calculation
    {
        public decimal Operand1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Operand2 { get; set; }
        public decimal Result { get; set; }

        public void Calculate()
        {
            Result = this.Operand1 + this.Operand2;
        }
    }
```

With a REST client, it should look like:
[image: Query using GET method]

#### With GET, data is sent via the URL

Note that if you use GET Method, the *server will expect to receive inputs from the URL*. You should therefore send queries like:
GET http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate?op1=1.0&op1=2.0&op2=3.0&op2=4.0

### Use POST method if operation is not idempotent

Since the operation does some server side calculation, I pretend it may not always be idempotent. If it is the case, POST might be more appropriate.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("calculate")]
    public List<Calculation> CalculateWithPost(CalculationInputs inputs)
    {
        var results = new List<Calculation>();
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.Operand2.Length; i++)
        {
            var calculation = new Calculation();
            calculation.Operand1 = inputs.Operand1[i];
            calculation.Operand2 = inputs.Operand2[i];
            calculation.Calculate();

            results.Add(calculation);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public class CalculationInputs
    {
        public decimal[] Operand1 { get; set; }
        public decimal[] Operand2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Calculation
    {
        public decimal Operand1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Operand2 { get; set; }
        public decimal Result { get; set; }

        public void Calculate()
        {
            Result = this.Operand1 + this.Operand2;
        }
    }
```

#### With POST, data is sent via the body

With that structure, *the server expects to receive inputs from the request body*. WebApi will deserialize the body if it matches the signature of your function.

With a REST client, it should look like:
[image: Query using POST method]

## Sidenote

The nuget package used to get the SwaggerUI generated (printscreens) can be find [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle). Very useful to run adhoc tests on WebApis.

Answer (score 4):

Add from [FromUri] before the parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<int> Calulate([FromUri] decimal[] op1, [FromUri] decimal[] op2)
```

> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the
>   [FromUri] attribute to the parameter

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass as a JSON array

http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate?op1=[1,2,3]&op2=[4,5,6]

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh - sorry abiout that....Well - seeing as this is your first test, maybe start with simple ints...
eg
public int Calulate(int op1, int op2)

http://localhost:50668/api/test/calculate?op1=6&op2=7

...and see how you get on with taht and then expand little by little.

I have an API that takes in an object, which contains a list of Ids and what I said works for me.

That said, it's pretty new to me too......so from experience I'd say start simple and work up..